# HTML Bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with bootstrap nav-tabs. I have this code. When I click on company button it shows me text in company and text in pressroom. When I click on press room button it shows me text only in press room and when I click on contacts button it shows me text in press room and contacts.

Any idea how solve this problem?

Thanks

```
<div class="about_us_links">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#company" data-toggle="tab">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pressroom" data-toggle="tab">Press Room</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts" data-toggle="tab">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="company" class="tab-pane fade in active">aaa</div>   
  <div id="pressroom" class="tabe-pane">bbb</div>
  <div id="contacts" class="tab-pane">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong class in `pressroom` div. it should be `tab-pane` instead of `tabe-pane`

```
<div id="pressroom" class="tab-pane">bbb</div>
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fWmA/)**

Comment: what about in angularjs project ? how is work bec. when you click tab refreshing html